# Infopath multiple selections

Tags: infopath

Hello  I have a 2 part question. Is it possible  to set a rule  to gray out a check mark in multiple selections example  if someone checks laptop1 on the list and submits it and the next person  wants to checks out same laptop but can't so I face them to select laptop #2. 2nd part is how I set a rule when laptop1  is return it ungrays  the check mark